# GUI patterns in Java/GWT - general approach

Tags: java, algorithm, user-interface, gwt, design-patterns

I'm helping to build a GWT application for a client and rewrote most of the stuff to work better, shorter code, faster, etc. However in all the GUI application I've worked on (not so many really) there comes a flexing point where you just have to put a lot of rules and move logic from the listeners to some common mediator. Then some times this could get an ugly mess so you whatever small think you need to do in the listener.

Let's take an example:

- form with 10-20 fields
- two exclusive radio control about half of the state of the other fields (enabling, validation, input limits)
- three exclusive radio controls control again almost the same fields, but in a different way (affecting calculations, enabling); they are also controlled by the above
- 4 or so number fields are validated on the fly depending on the previous selections and some real-time data object; they can have upper/lower limits, be enabled/disabled
- one drop-down box controls the next 6 or so controls - displaying/hiding them, modifying validators
- some checkboxes (shown by the above combo) activate some input fields and also determine their validation algorithm

While everything is up an running, without known bugs, there are a few coding gotchas that really bother me:

- code is spread among listeners and some mediator methods.
- loading the form with some preset values presents its own challenges: like data objects that might be available or not, data objects that might alter their state and subsequent field behaviour
- some fields are having a default value set and this should not be overwritten by automatic filling, but if the data objects are not there (yet) then they will need to be filled eventually when the later become available
- form cannot be submitted if any of the fields are not validated

My approach:

- identify which fields share a common afair and move code into one place
- each radio group shares a single listener implementation between its radios
- default form filling is deferred until the live data is available (as much as possible) and as a result it gets called multiple times
- each action has a call to a common validator method
- the validator runs through all the fields in the form, calls their validators (which highlight all errors) and returns a single boolean
- each relevant keypress or mouse action, data change it gets deferred to be called after 250ms from the last call; this means first call just places the validator as a delayed action, subsequent calls reset the timer

Ok, it doesn't make any sense to dwelve into more details but I'm more upset about the fact that there is no clear separation between visual actions (enabling), data actions (setting form field values), field listeners, retrieving form values and live data listeners.

What would be a good approach/pattern (next time maybe) to make sure that MVC get separated and lends itself better to maintenance? I know this is not a typical question but I've read every documentation I could get my hands on and still did not find some helpful answer.

Comment: Avoid using too many listeners(isn't it deprecated anyways?), don't make the program too chatty. Use MVP, club similar functionality sets into their own widgets. Otherwise hell will break loose when you want to debug your program after 6 months.

Comment: Even though I have accepted the best answer so far I am still open to any suggestions. Just for later reference, I am adding another resource: http://code.google.com/p/acris/wiki/MVP_Acris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd move closer towards MVP than MVC.  It's clearly the way Google intends to go, so adopting it will probably mean that you're able to ***go with the flow*** rather than ***fight the current***.

How does this affect you?  Well, I believe you should accept that a tidier implementation may involve more code: not the 'shorter code' you were hoping for.  But, if it's logically structured, efficient code the Google compiler should be able to trim lots out in the compiler optimisation phase.

So, move as much of the logic as you can into the model layer. Test this thoroughly, and verify that the correct level of page reset/tidying happens (all of this can be done with plain JUnit, without any UI).  Next, use your Presenter (Activity) to tie the View to the Model: handling the interactions, populating the fields, etc.

Comment: I didn't about https://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html . My problem is that most of the code I'm working on is inherited AND that this is my first experience with GWT, so any kind of suggestions are appreciated. I've taken a look at how GXT and other applications/frameworks are implemented but that only gets me so far.

Comment: Also, I'm not 'afraid' of more code, but in GWT that almost always translates more interpreted Javascript and this form should be fast. I don't even know how to profile it - Speedtracer gives me some info but in compiled mode it's hard to see what impact Java code has. Plus, it worries me that I've already begun to use deferred calls to slow down some actions - in my book that translates to unknown flow. Would be great to also have a pattern like: you can execute this actions paralleled, this next action has a dependency on that one. Like OSs where they load drivers or services at startup.

Comment: Hi there brainwash.  Yes GWT may produce a lot of code. Typically, however its the minimum code needed to support your Java code across the range of selected browsers (its the price to pay for cross-browser code).  The GWT compiler stage only writes js for GWT APIs that are actually called by your code: so it's producing the bare minimum code to meet your requirement. Beyond that, you can use Code Splitting to ensure only application capabilities used by the current user come down from the server.  I can't help with deferred calls, but what you describe seems to be something you code yourself

Answer (score 0):

you can divide a Huge class in different classes bu dividing the GUI in different JPanels. All the panels are implemented in different classes extending JPanel. Guess that would help you.